# Why does lying down after meal cause diarrhea?

Tags: digestion

Quite often if I lie down not long after a meal, I will have diarrhea. Why is that?

Will any other actions after a meal have similar effect?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to health.SE! Unfortunately, this is not something we can address. For diagnosis, please see a doctor.

Comment: As stated, this is not something that we can diagnose. Your best option is to talk to your personal health care provider with your questions.